# Is it possible to do a lazy groupby, returning a stream, in java 8?

Tags: java, lazy-loading, java-8, java-stream

I have some large-ish text files that I want to process by grouping its lines.

I tried to use the new streaming features, like

```
return FileUtils.readLines(...) 
            .parallelStream()
            .map(...)
            .collect(groupingBy(pair -> pair[0]));
```

The problem is that, AFAIK, this generates a Map.

Is there any way to have high level code like the one above that generates, for example, a Stream of Entries?

**UPDATE**: What I'm looking for is something like python's [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). My files are already sorted (by pair[0]), I just want to load the groups one by one.

I already have an iterative solution. I'm just wondering if there's a more declarative way to do that. Btw, using guava or another 3rd party library wouldn't be a big problem.

Comment: How can you do a lazy group-by? In order to group-by some property of the object contained in the Stream, you have to iterate over all the elements in the Stream.

Comment: What do you mean by "grouping its lines?" do you mean binning like the Stream `groupBy` method or do you mean reading multiple lines at a time in bulk?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, added an UPDATE to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The task you want to achieve is quite different from what grouping does. `groupingBy` does not rely on the order of the `Stream`’s elements but on the `Map`’s algorithm applied to the classifier `Function`’s result.

What you want is to fold adjacent items having a common property value into one `List` item. It is not even necessary to have the `Stream` sorted by that property as long as you can guaranty that all items having the same property value are clustered.

Maybe it is possible to formulate this task as a reduction but to me the resulting structure looks too complicated.

So, unless direct support for this feature gets added to the `Stream`s, an iterator based approach looks most pragmatic to me:

```
class Folding<T,G> implements Spliterator<Map.Entry<G,List<T>>> {
    static <T,G> Stream<Map.Entry<G,List<T>>> foldBy(
            Stream<? extends T> s, Function<? super T, ? extends G> f) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(new Folding<>(s.spliterator(), f), false);
    }
    private final Spliterator<? extends T> source;
    private final Function<? super T, ? extends G> pf;
    private final Consumer<T> c=this::addItem;
    private List<T> pending, result;
    private G pendingGroup, resultGroup;

    Folding(Spliterator<? extends T> s, Function<? super T, ? extends G> f) {
        source=s;
        pf=f;
    }
    private void addItem(T item) {
        G group=pf.apply(item);
        if(pending==null) pending=new ArrayList<>();
        else if(!pending.isEmpty()) {
            if(!Objects.equals(group, pendingGroup)) {
                if(pending.size()==1)
                    result=Collections.singletonList(pending.remove(0));
                else {
                    result=pending;
                    pending=new ArrayList<>();
                }
                resultGroup=pendingGroup;
            }
        }
        pendingGroup=group;
        pending.add(item);
    }
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super Map.Entry<G, List<T>>> action) {
        while(source.tryAdvance(c)) {
            if(result!=null) {
                action.accept(entry(resultGroup, result));
                result=null;
                return true;
            }
        }
        if(pending!=null) {
            action.accept(entry(pendingGroup, pending));
            pending=null;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    private Map.Entry<G,List<T>> entry(G g, List<T> l) {
        return new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(g, l);
    }
    public int characteristics() { return 0; }
    public long estimateSize() { return Long.MAX_VALUE; }
    public Spliterator<Map.Entry<G, List<T>>> trySplit() { return null; }
}
```

The lazy nature of the resulting folded `Stream` can be best demonstrated by applying it to an infinite stream:

```
Folding.foldBy(Stream.iterate(0, i->i+1), i->i>>4)
       .filter(e -> e.getKey()>5)
       .findFirst().ifPresent(e -> System.out.println(e.getValue()));
```

Comment: slight correction: `groupingBy` does indeed preserve the ordering of the original stream, if the downstream collector cooperates (most do, except those with the UNORDERED characteristic); the subset of elements in any given bucket are presented to the downstream collector in the same order that they were present in the input.

Comment: @Brian Goetz: yes, it *maintains* the order, but all I said in my answer is that it doesn’t *rely* on the order for forming the groups. Btw. that was one of the test cases I made for my solution: collecting a stream returned by my solution into a `Map` must produce exactly the same `Map` as `groupingBy` using the same classifier.

Answer (score 1):

[cyclops-react](https://github.com/aol/simple-react), I library a contribute to, offers both [sharding](https://github.com/aol/simple-react/wiki/Batching,-Time-Control,-Sharding-and-Zipping-Operators) and grouping funcitonality that might do what you want.

```
  ReactiveSeq<ListX<TYPE>> grouped = ReactiveSeq.fromCollection(FileUtils.readLines(...) )
             .groupedStatefullyWhile((batch,next) ->  batch.size()==0 ? true : next.equals(batch.get(0)));
```

The groupedStatefullyWhile operator allows elements to be grouped based on the current state of the batch. ReactiveSeq is a single threaded sequential Stream.

```
  Map<Key, Stream<Value> sharded = 
                  new LazyReact()
                 .fromCollection(FileUtils.readLines(...) )
                 .map(..)
                 .shard(shards, pair -> pair[0]);
```

This will create a LazyFutureStream (that implements java.util.stream.Stream), that will process the data in the file asynchronously and in parallel. It's lazy and won't start processing until data is pulled through.

The only caveat is that you need to define the shards beforehand. I.e. the 'shards' parameter above which is a Map of async.Queue's keyed by the key to the shard (possibly whatever pair[0] is?).

e.g.

```
Map<Integer,Queue<String>> shards;
```

[There is a sharding example with video here](https://medium.com/@johnmcclean/reactive-programming-with-java-8-and-simple-react-sharding-c766019153b5) and  [test code here](https://github.com/aol/simple-react/blob/master/src/test/java/com/aol/simple/react/lazy/Tutorial.java)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by `collapse` with [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex)

```
final int[][] aa = { { 1, 1 }, { 1, 2 }, { 2, 2 }, { 2, 3 }, { 3, 3 }, { 4, 4 } };

StreamEx.of(aa)
        .collapse((a, b) -> a[0] == b[0], Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a[0]))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

We can add `peek` and `limit` to verify if it's lazy calculation:

```
StreamEx.of(aa)
        .peek(System.out::println)
        .collapse((a, b) -> a[0] == b[0], Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a[0]))
        .limit(1)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```