# How to implement a Java stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to implement a `Stream<T>`.

I don't want to just use `implements Stream<T>`, because I would have to implement a ton of methods.

Can this be avoided?

To be more concrete, how can I stream `t1`, `t2` and `t3` for example:

```
class Foo<T> {
    T t1, t2, t3;

    Foo(T t1, T t2, T t3) {
        this.t1 = t1;
        this.t2 = t2;
        this.t3 = t3;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Stream.of(t1, t2, t3)`.

Comment: [`Stream.builder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#builder--)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The JDK's standard implementation of `Stream` is the internal class `java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline`, you cannot instantiate it directly.

Instead you can use `java.util.stream.Stream.builder()`, `java.util.stream.StreamSupport.stream(Spliterator<T>, boolean)` and various<sup>[1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T...-), [2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamSources)</sup> other static factory methods to create an instance of the default implementation.

Using a spliterator is probably the most powerful approach as it allows you to provide objects lazily while also enabling efficient parallelization if your source can be divided into multiple chunks.

Additionally you can also convert streams back into spliterators, wrap them in a custom spliterator and then convert them back into a stream if you need to implement your own *stateful intermediate operations* - e.g. due to shortcomings in the standard APIs - since most available intermediate ops [are not allowed to be stateful](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness).
See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28363324/1362755) for an example.

In principle you could write your own implementation of the stream interface, but that would be quite tedious.

Comment: But `Spliterator` isn't closable and my data source is :(

Answer (score 23):

If you're wanting to make your own Stream because you want custom `close()` logic, the simplest solution is to create a Stream from an Iterator, and call [`onClose(Runnable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#onClose-java.lang.Runnable-). For instance, to stream from a Reader via Jackson:

```java
MappingIterator<?> values = objectMapper.reader(type).readValues(reader);
return StreamSupport
        .stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(values, Spliterator.ORDERED), false)
        .onClose(() -> {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 18):

You usually do not need to write your own stream class. Instead you can create stream by existing methods. For instance, here is how to create a stream of the value 1, 100:

```
  AtomicInteger n = new AtomicInteger(0);
  Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.generate(() -> n.incrementAndGet()).limit(100);
```

so in here we created an infinite stream of integers: 1, 2, 3, .... then we used `limit(100)` on that infinite stream to get back a stream of 100 elements.

For clarity, if you want a stream of integers (at fixed intervals) you should use `IntStream.range()`.  This is just an example to show how streams can be defined using `Stream.generate()` which gives you more flexibility as it allows you to use arbitrary logic for determining steam's elements.

Comment: `IntStream.range(0,100)` would be more efficient in this case.

Comment: This can be shortened to `Stream.generate(n::incrementAndGet).limit(100)`

Comment: Use `n::getAndIncrement` if you want the stream to start at 0.

Answer (score 11):

Others have answered how to provide a general-purpose `Stream` implementation. Regarding your *specific* requirement, just do this:

```
class Foo<T> {

    T t1, t2, t3;

    Foo(T t1, T t2, T t3) {
        this.t1 = t1;
        this.t2 = t2;
        this.t3 = t3;
    }

    Stream<T> stream() {
        return Stream.of(t1, t2, t3);
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is both concise and idiomatic (at least, it mimics the stream methods in the std lib). So I'd say it should be higher up.

Answer (score 11):

For the sake of completeness, as I did not find this directly among the answers here on SO: 
If you want to transform an existing Iterator into a Stream (e.g., because you want to generate elements successively), use this:

```
StreamSupport.stream(
    Spliterators.spliterator(myIterator, /* initial size*/ 0L, Spliterator.NONNULL), 
    /* not parallel */ false);
```

I found this a bit hard to find, as you need to know StreamSupport, Spliterators and Spliterator

Comment: This is useful, thanks!
Note that the parameter you've called "initial size" is actually the stream's estimated size. Not exactly sure what that is used for but it seems to play a role in whether a stream is parallelisable and I think that passing `0` here rules out concurrency entirely. `Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(myIterator, Spliterator.NONNULL)` would use `Long.MAX_VALUE` as the estimate instead.

Comment: @sqweek As the docs say: "The spliterator is only traversed, split, or queried for estimated size after the terminal operation of the stream pipeline commences". So if spliterator's underlying iterator contains more elements than size value, they won't be acquired/get/collected.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not a good solution for your example with finitely many values, as this question comes up in searches for how to implement a stream, it’s perhaps worthwhile to mention a simple way to implement an infinite stream, [`Stream.generate(Supplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate(java.util.function.Supplier)), for example:

```
    return Stream.generate(() -> Math.random());
```