# Java 8 extending stream<T>

Tags: java, casting, java-8, java-stream

I'm attempting to extend Java 8's Stream implementation.

I have this interface:

```
public interface StreamStuff<T> extends Stream<T> {

    Stream<T> delegate();
    default Stream<T> biggerThanFour() {
        return delegate().filter(i -> ((Double)i > 4));
    }
}
```

And in my main method:

```
int arr [] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

Object array [] = ((StreamStuff)Arrays
            .stream(arr))
            .biggerThanFour()
            .toArray();
```

I'm trying to cast the Stream, to my interface StreamStuff, and use my method.

Im getting the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.stream.IntPipeline$Head cannot be cast to StreamStuff

I get the same error when I do:

`StreamStuff ss = (StreamStuff)Arrays.stream(arr);`

I'm wondering if this sort of thing is even possible and if so, how do I achieve this? For reference I'm kind of using [this article](http://benjiweber.co.uk/blog/2015/03/06/adding-tolist-to-java-streams/) as a guide.

Comment: How do you intend for the method `Arrays.stream` to know about your extending interface? Look at the article again, notably their `EnhancedList`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to implement a Stream<T> for java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685623/how-to-implement-a-streamt-for-java)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already mentioned, you can create your own wrapper implementation:

```
public class MyStream<T> implements Stream<T> {

    private final Stream<T> delegate;

    public MyStream(Stream<T> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public Stream<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
        return delegate.filter(predicate);
    }

    @Override
    public void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        delegate.forEach(action);
    }

    MyStream<T> biggerThanFour() {
        return new MyStream<>(delegate.filter(i -> ((Double) i > 4)));
    }

    // all other methods from the interface
}
```

You will have to delegate all methods from the interface, so the class will be pretty big. You might consider adding a class `StreamWrapper` which will delegate all methods from the interface and then have your actual class `StreamStuff` extend `StreamWrapper`. This would allow you to have only your custom methods in `StreamStuff` and no other stream methods. You might also make all overridden methods in `StreamWrapper` final to avoid accidentally overriding them.

Then you can use it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream<Double> orgStream = Stream.of(1.0, 3.0, 7.0, 2.0, 9.0);

    MyStream<Double> myStream = new MyStream<>(orgStream);

    myStream.biggerThanFour().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

The custom method returns a new wrapper so you can chain calls to your custom methods.

Just note that your cast to `Double` might throw `ClassCastException` so you might consider replacing generic `T` with `Double`, hence limiting the delegate stream to be of that specific type.

Comment: Except, as soon as you call a real Stream method, it will return a Stream, not a MyStream.  So you can't, for example, call `map()` and then call `biggerThanFour`.  You'd need to wrap the result at each stage and covariantly override all the stream-bearing methods.

Comment: @BrianGoetz good point. That effectively means reimplementing Stream API, because if we want to change return types, we can no longer use Stream interface...

Comment: You *can* change the return type, if you are narrowing the type, so implementing stream methods by changing the return type from `Stream<X>` to `MyStream<X>` is no problem. This implies that you have to re-wrap the result of each intermediate operation, e.g. `@Override public MyStream<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate) { return new MyStream<>(delegate.filter(predicate)); }`. It’s no that different to your existing code.

Answer (score 7):

You are calling `stream()` on the `Arrays` class, which creates its own `Stream` implementation without any connection to yours. You'd have to produce the `Stream` yourself, or wrap a stream you obtained elsewhere, in order for something like this to work. Something like this:

```
int[] filtered = new StreamStuff(Arrays.stream(arr)).biggerThanFour().toArray();
```

However, in your case, why don't you just filter?

```
int[] filtered = Arrays.stream(arr).filter(i -> i > 4).toArray();
```

Comment: The .biggerThanFour() method is arbitrary. I'm trying to figure out how to write my own methods to use in a stream pipeline. If that makes sense

Comment: @LiamFerris Yes, that makes sense. You can look at the [`StreamEx`](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library for more examples; it may even provide what you need already.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look :) Appreciate the help

Comment: Even worse, `Arrays.stream(int[])` doesn’t even return a `Stream`…

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is, if you don't want to handle all the `Stream<T>` delegates and new methods in the future, to use an Interface with a more wrapped lambda stream method:

```
public interface MyStream<T> {

    Stream<T> stream();

    static <T> MyStream<T> of(Stream<T> stream) {
        return () -> stream;
    }

    default <U> MyStream<U> stream(Function<Stream<T>, Stream<U>> stream) {
        return of(stream.apply(stream()));
    }

    //Watch out with Double cast. Check the type in method or restrict it via generic
    default MyStream<T> biggerThanFour() {
        return of(stream().filter(i -> ((Double) i > 4)));
    }

    //Watch out with Double cast. Check the type in method or restrict it via generic
    //Another method
    default MyStream<T> biggerThanFourteen() {
        return of(stream().filter(i -> ((Double) i > 14)));
    }
}
```

So you have your Interface with your delegate here `stream()` method which also handles the base stream terminal methods,
 the static creation method `of(...)`,
 again a `stream(...)` method but with a `Function<T,U>` as parameter for handling the base Stream intermediate methods
 and of course your custom methods like `biggerThanFour()`.
So the drawback is here that you cant extend directly from `Stream<T>` (unfortunately the `Stream<T>` has not only default methods for one standard implementation)
to bypass the delegates.
Also the handling is a small drawback but I think in most cases it's fine e.g.:

```
List<Integer> doubles = MyStream.of(Stream.of(1.0, 3.0, 7.0, 2.0, 9.0)) // create instance
                .biggerThanFour() //call MyStream methods
                .stream(doubleStream -> doubleStream.map(aDouble -> aDouble * 2)) //Do youre base stream intermediate methods and return again MyStream so you can call more specific custom methods
                .biggerThanFourteen()
                .stream() // call the base stream more or less your delegate for last intermediate methods and terminal method
                .mapToInt(Double::intValue)
                .boxed() //Ah if you have IntStreams and similar you can call the boxed() method to get an equivalent stream method.
                .collect(Collectors.toList()); // terminal method call
```

So list content is [18] ;)