# How does `() -> delegate` wrap a Stream?

Tags: java, generics, java-stream

Not sure how to write the question, but I saw the following construct in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45971597/242042

```
public interface MyStream<T> {
    Stream<T> stream();
    static <T> MyStream<T> of(Stream<T> stream) {
        return () -> stream;
    }
}
```

Which I used in my answer https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/400492/42195

The `of` method returns a Callable that returns the delegate stream.  But how did that even translate to `<T> MyStream <T>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier to understand if you separate the code a little more:

```java
public interface MyStream<T> {
    Stream<T> stream();
}
class Util {
    static <T> MyStream<T> of(Stream<T> stream) {
        return () -> stream;
    }
}
```

It is still doing the same thing, but it is a little easier to follow.

Then in a second step, let's write this without a lamda expression in the "classic" way:

```java
public interface MyStream<T> {
    Stream<T> stream();
}
class Util {
    static <T> MyStream<T> of(Stream<T> stream) {
        return new MyStream<>() {
            Stream<T> stream() {
                return stream;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

What you are doing here is create an anonymous class, that implements the interaface `MyStream`. It has a method `stream` which returns the `stream` you passed as method argument.

Now with Java 8 there is this fancy new format to write things. This is possible if the interface has only a single method. In this case the `new Stream` is not necessary, because the compiler knows the type from the return type of your method. Also the `Stream<T> stream()` definition is not necessary, because the compiler knows it from the interface definition. And in case of a single statement, you can even omit the `return`, because the compile will assume the result of the single statement to be the return-value.

Thus this:

```java
return new MyStream<>() {
    Stream<T> stream() {
        return stream;
    }
};
```

can be written as:

```java
  () -> stream;
//      ^^^^^^^ Return value
//^^ Argument list (in this case empty)
```

Comment: Ah so the key part was the "single method".  That's good because when I tried to let IntelliJ do an "extract local variable" it gave me `Callable<Stream<T>>` but that didn't match the signature

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano: You can also annotate your interface with `@FunctionalInterface`, then the compiler checks that the interface is suitable for use in lampda-expressions.

Answer (score 2):

What you are returning from your static `of(Stream<T> stream)` method is basically the functional interface `MyStream<T>` implementation

The lambda `() -> stream` is then implementation of `Stream<T> stream()` method (because it's the only one to be overridden) and because `stream` is of `Stream<T>` type everything is good here

Read more about functional interfaces here: [What is use of Functional Interface in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881826/what-is-use-of-functional-interface-in-java-8)