# Simplest way to create a stream from a Java object?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

With `Collection` everything is clear, but what about the following:

There is an `object` with a `count()` method and a `getPart(int i)` method. So extracting all objects leads to the following boilerplate code:

```
List<Part> result = new ArrayList<Part>();
for (int i = 0, i < object.count(), i++) {
    result.add(object.getPart(i));        
}
return result.stream();
```

Is there any standard way to pass just 2 producers: `() -> object.count()` and `(int i) -> object.getPart(i)` to create a stream? Like this:

```
SomeUtil.stream(object::count, object::getPart);
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685623/how-to-implement-a-streamt-for-java) seems similar, maybe it can help

Comment: Because there is no method `getParts`. :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try this:

```
IntStream.range(0, object.count()).mapToObj(object::getPart);
```

Comment: I lost track of how many times the solution to a "how do I create a stream from this weird thing"-problem was an `IntStream` solution! :D