# How can I add two IntStreams element by element?

Tags: java, java-stream

Example;

```
IntStream a = create(3, 1);  // => [0,0,1]
IntStream b = create(5, 2);  // => [0,0,0,0,2]
```

The first stream gives an infinite stream of `[0,0,1,0,0,1...]` and the second an infinite stream of `[0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,...]`.

The result stream is ri = ai + bi meaning that I just want to take the sum of the elements at the same position from each stream.

Is this possible in Java ?

Comment: Implementing a `Spliterator` is apparently the best method: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30685623/1896169

Comment: what is `create` ?

Comment: @YCF_L. This is clearly explained in the question.

Comment: Also very relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17640754/2988730

Comment: i'm really don't get it, i'm not familiar so much with streams so i don't know how create look like @MadPhysicist can you guide me please?

Comment: @YCF_L For test purposes, just have an ArrayList with 15 elements for each case and call `toStream` or whatever on it. No need to make this complicated

Comment: So, the result for the given example with `[0, 0, 1, …]` and `[0, 0, 0, 0, 2, …]` would be `[0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, …]`?

Comment: @beatngu13. If the 15th element is 3, then yes. This looks like FizzBuzz now that you put it that way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zipping streams using JDK8 with lambda (java.util.stream.Streams.zip)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Guava's [`Streams.zip()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#zip-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.function.BiFunction-) helper:

```
IntStream sum(IntStream a, IntStream b) {
    return Streams.zip(a.boxed(), b.boxed(), Integer::sum)
            .map(Integer::intValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own Spliterator to create a stream from it later.

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Spliterators;
import java.util.function.IntConsumer;

public class SumSpliterator extends Spliterators.AbstractIntSpliterator {
    private OfInt aSplit;
    private OfInt bSplit;

    SumSpliterator(OfInt a, OfInt b) {
        super(Math.min(a.estimateSize(), b.estimateSize()), Spliterator.ORDERED);
        aSplit = a;
        bSplit = b;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(IntConsumer action) {
        SummingConsumer consumer = new SummingConsumer();
        if (aSplit.tryAdvance(consumer) && bSplit.tryAdvance(consumer)) {
            action.accept(consumer.result);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    static class SummingConsumer implements IntConsumer {
        int result;
        @Override
        public void accept(int value) {
            result += value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then create a stream and check the results

```
IntStream a = //create stream a
IntStream b = //create stream b
SumSpliterator spliterator = new SumSpliterator(a.spliterator(), b.spliterator());
Stream<Integer> stream = StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, false);
stream.limit(20).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I’d use `Math.min(a.estimateSize(), b.estimateSize())` as estimated size…