# Java custom function on stream

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Say I have something like

```
something.stream()
         .filter(filterMethod) // Same
         .map(mapMethod)       //
         .map(somethingElse)
         .filter(filterMethod) // Same
         .map(mapMethod)       //
         .filter(otherFilter)
         .filter(filterMethod) // Same
         .map(mapMethod)       //
```

Could I create custom function on Stream and convert .filter().map() to one method? Implementing own `Stream` seems to overkill. It would be nice to have some short lambda function or method like

```
Stream<T> fooFiterMap(Stream<T> stream){
    return stream.filter(filterMethod).map(mapMethod);
}
```

and then reduce my `something` stream into

```
something.stream()
         .fooFilterMap()     // New
         .map(somethingElse)
         .fooFilterMap()     // New
         .filter(otherFilter)
         .fooFilterMap()     // New
```

Comment: You mean like `something.stream().myFilterAndMap().myFilterAndMap().myFilterAndMap()`?

Comment: That seems pretty hard to do. My guess is you would have to write your own Stream interface (extends Stream) to begin with.

Comment: @PaulLemarchand: _if_ that is the question, then indeed it is, and then it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685623/how-to-implement-a-java-stream :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement a Java stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685623/how-to-implement-a-java-stream)

Comment: Writing own interface seems like an overkill. Isn't there something like:

Stream<T> myFilterAndMap(Stream<T> stream){
   return stream.filter(filterMethod).map(mapMethod);
}

Comment: what would you gain with this? one more level of indirection?

Comment: @Eugene It would reduce number of steps many-fold and, using proper naming convention, we could earn some clarity.

Comment: `number of  steps many-fold`? I wish I could say I understood what you just said

Comment: @Eugene Seeing your answer I understand what you thought of. My use case is as simple as: stream.myFilterMap().map(somethingElse).myFilterMap().filter(otherFilter);
and that .myFilterMap() is repeated many times in many methods.

Comment: yeah... you can't do that obviously without extending `Stream` in the first place (`StreamEx` library has done it for example); but looks like a big overkill here

Comment: @Eugene when you say "obviously" it's really not obvious to me why. Any chance you could add this explanation to your answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can obviously write your own one:

```
<T> Stream<T> fooFiterMap(Stream<T> stream, Predicate<T> predicate, UnaryOperator<T> function) {
    return stream.filter(predicate).map(function);
}
```

But the real question is why? It's too verbose? If so, than I'll argue - I like the chaining of `filter` and `map` more - bit it's subjective I guess.
If you think about multiple objects created, than just think about the fact that these are probably stateless lambdas used on the same call-site, thus a single instance of `Predicate` and `Function`.

Comment: The OP doesn’t want a method for combining an arbitrary `Predicate` and an arbitrary `Function`/`UnaryOperator`. The OP wants to repeatedly apply the *same* filter and map function, so that not specifying the functions again would truly shorten the code, though, I admittedly can’t imagine real life scenarios for that…

Comment: @Holger I do: your own snippet of `filter(T.class::isInstance).map(T.class::cast)`

Comment: @PostSelf how would `T.class` work? I don't get your example here

Comment: Probably not, I don't get this whole Java syntax, but you should get the meaning (filtering and downcasting).