# Java 8 GroupingBy into Peek

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I recently learned about streams in Java 8 and started to work with them. Now I have a question regarding the `groupingBy` collector method:

Usually I work with .NET, so I compared (knowing they are **not** the same) Java `Stream<T>` with .NET `IEnumerable<T>`. Following this comparison, `List<T>` stores elements and the particular `Stream`/`IEnumerable` applies operations. One example:

C#:

```
elements.Where(x => x.Value == 5).ToList();
```

Java:

```
elements.stream().filter(x -> x.getValue() == 5).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In both examples, I start with a list, define operations (a filter in this example) and collect the result to store it (in a new list in this example).

Now I got a more complex case:

```
data.stream()
    .map( ... ).filter( ... ) // Some operations
    .collect(groupingBy(Chunk::getName, summingLong(Chunk::getValue)));
```

The result of this query is a `Map<String, Long>` and I can work with this, but lets say, I want to proceed with this data instead of storing it. My current approach is trivial:

```
    ...
    .collect(groupingBy(Chunk::getName, summingLong(Chunk::getValue)))
    .entrySet().stream().
    .map( ... ) // Do more operations
```

But this way, I leave the stream, store the first result in a Map and open a new stream to continue. Is there a way to group without a collector, so that I can "stay" in the stream?

Comment: Since you're grouping, you pretty much have to go to an intermediate store - what if you need to group a value at the start of the stream with a value at the end? You'd need to process "everything", storing it until you're sure there's nothing more to group with. So internally, Java would have to (/could?) put things in a map (or some similar structure) anyway; what's so bad about doing this yourself?

Comment: It's not really a problem, I can live with my trivial approach, but in all my other stream operations there was a clear line between having a `List` and having a `Stream`. I opened it, operated on it and collected it. Now there is a Map, that gets opened for a new stream, so I was wondering if its possible with another approach.

Comment: Maybe I got confused by my .NET background. There you can do any operation on an `IEnumerable` and in the end you collect your result via `ToList`, `ToArray`, `ToDictionary` or by iterating over it.

Comment: This could be achieved by creating a custom `Spliterator`. Here is a post which describes how to turn a simple `groupBy` into a non terminal lazy `partitionBy`: [Partition a stream by a discriminator function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28363324/7274990)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the API is right now, you can't escape it.

> groupingBy

is a terminal operation (it does not return a Stream), so that operation will end the stream.

Depending on what you want later to do inside the last map operation, you could create a custom collector that will "stay" inside the stream; even if inside you would probably still gather elements into a Map.

Comment: Is there any collector operation which is not terminal? If not, I assume this is by design, so it would be better to manually open a new stream, am I right?

Answer (score 6):

You can do whatever you like in the downstream collector, as long as you can describe the operation as a `Collector`. Currently, there is only an equivalent to the intermediate operation `map`, the [`mapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) collector, but Java 9 will also add [`filtering`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#filtering-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.stream.Collector-) and [`flatMapping`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) (which you could also implement yourself in Java 8) and there’s already an equivalent to almost every terminal operation.

Of course, a nested appliance of collectors will look entirely different than a chain of Stream operations doing the same…

If, however, you want to process complete groups, there is no way around completing the `grouping` collection first. This is not a limitation of the API, but intrinsic to the grouping operation or any operation in general, if you want to process a complete result, you’ll need to complete the operation first. Regardless of how the API looks like, e.g. you could hide the follow-up operation in the collector in a [`collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-)-like manner, creating and populating the `Map` is unavoidable, as it’s the map doing the maintenance of the groups. The groups are determined by the keys and lookup logic of the `Map`, so, e.g. using a `SortedMap` with a custom comparator or an `IdentityHashMap`, can change the grouping logic entirely.